# Using IQueryable in onPost method

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

In my .net-core project I'm trying to edit a list of data which I query from DB using LINQ.

I can display this data in the table, no problem, but once I click "Submit" data, I get the following exception:

"Model bound complex types must not be abstract or value types and must have a parameterless constructor."

and my IQueryable is set to null

So, I have a class, let say

```
class MyRecord
{
  [Key]
  public int recordID {get; set;}

  public int recordType {get; set;}

  public String recordName {get; set;}
}
```

then I create IQueryable list:

```
[BindProperty]
public IQueryable<MyRecord> myRecordListQuery
```

and select from Database a list of records

```
myRecordListQuery = (from r in _context.RecordTable
                     where r.recordType == 0
                     select r);
```

so, up to here it works fine, I get my set of records and can work with them in the Razor Page (not MVC!), something like creating a HTML table and using my results in a form of:

```
<td>
<input asp-for="@Model.myRecordListQuery.Skip(i).First().recordName" class="form-control" />
</td>
```

So, records are correctly displayed and can be edited.

The problem is, when I submit form, I get the exception written above...

p.s. If I use List instead of IQueryable, it returns correct data on post method, but then it's not that ease to update a database - either I need to compare values (was / is) or update all records what is inefficient from my perspective.

Would be thankful for any advise!

Answer (score 2):

The exception tells you the problem and how to fix it: you can't bind to an `IQueryable`, you need something like `List<T>`:

```
[BindProperty]
public List<MyRecord> myRecordListQuery
```

You really shouldn't be passing an `IQueryable` to your view *anyways*. Materialize the resultset in your code-behind.

Answer (score 0):

If your contraint is that you need to use IQueryable to "easily update your database", you can make "myRecordListQuery" a list for use in the view and then, in your post method, you cast the data back to IQueryable, so in your get method you can do something like this.

```
[BindProperty]
public List<MyRecord> myRecordListQuery;
```

Then in your post you can have cast the returned value to an IQueryable

```
IQueryable<MyRecord> iQueryableMyRecord = myRecordListQuery.AsQueryable();
```

Comment: Thanks for the right direction! Casting did not work ut but this did: IQueryable<MyRecord> iQueryableMyRecord = myRecordListQuery.AsQueryable();